# simple jquery .post not returning data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .post

jquery statement:

```
$.post ('test.php', {f1: 'abc', f2: 'def'}, function (data) {console.log (data)})
```

test.php:

```
 <?php
        $f1 = $_REQUEST ['f1'];
        $f2 = $_REQUEST ['f2'];

        echo $f1 . $f2;
?>
```

After invoking the jquery statement, nothing gets returned which should be seen in the console area.

Running test.html, however, the browser shows 'f1f2' as expected.  test.html:

```
<form action='test.php' method="post">
    <label>f1</label>
    <input name="f1" type="text">
    <label>f2</label>
    <input name="f2" type="text">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Why is there no return data to the jquery post request?

Comment: is there any error in the browser console

Comment: No, there is no error showing in the browser console.

Comment: For getting data use $_POST['f1'] instead of $_REQUEST['f1']

Comment: plz paste you complete test.html

Comment: When I ran the test.html case, I entered 'f1' and 'f2', respectively in the input fields.  I should have entered 'abc' and 'def' respectively to avoid confusion.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Complete test.html:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action='test.php' method="post">
        <label>f1</label>
        <input name="f1" type="text">
        <label>f2</label>
        <input name="f2" type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @Gul Muhammad Akbari, when I use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST, I get the exact same thing:  test.html successfully returns, but the jquery statement does not.

Comment: Did the below solution worked for you ? if not tell me from where you are invoking jquery statment  ? where it is included

Comment: So now I created a super simple html case and it works. I still don't understand why does the $.post works in this new test case, but not in my code.  Other jquery statements work just fine. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $.post ('test.php', {f1: 'abc', f2: 'def'}, function (data) {console.log (data)})
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Is formatting possible in a comment?  I tired the 4 space insert trick, but the lines still get smashed together.

Comment: preventDefault was missing in the submit function (below).

Comment: Would someone kindly please tell me why they downvoted my question?

Comment: @tgoneil it says unclear what you are asking , you should clarify your question then.

Comment: Good point.  I should have asked the question very first thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
        $f1 = $_POST ['f1'];
        $f2 = $_POST ['f2'];

        echo $f1 . $f2;
    ?>
```

and if you want to post using jquery , dont submit your form , preventDefault on submit , and trigger the post submit.

```
$("#yourFormId").submit(function(e){e.preventDefault();$.post ('test.php', {f1: 'abc', f2: 'def'}, function (data) {console.log (data)})})
```

Comment: Please clarify the preventDefault on submit.

Comment: @tgoneil preventDefault will not trigger submit but will instead post data to your php.

Comment: @tgoneil if you wanna use submit , then you should not use jquery post.

Comment: Is that $.post statement I gave expected to post to test.php or does it need to be modified?

Comment: @tgoneil no your post doesnt need modification , but you need to trigger it using some event.

Comment: @tgoneil i dont get it , why are you using a form , when you are posting static data ?!

Comment: That was it!!!  preventDefault was what I had neglected to use in jquery's submit function.  Thank you ProllyGeek!!